# Saving Processing algorithm output to string instead of file.geojson

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3

Is there any way to save `processing.run("native:algorithm")` output directly to string instead of file or temporary layer?

I'm aware of saving output to layer and exporting features using `QgsJsonExporter()`, however it adds ID to every feature therefore it's not what I'm looking for.

Now I'm going for approach where extra ID is generated for every feature in geojson result is generated. However then I change `OUTPUT` to `file.geojson` there are no extra IDs.

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer(sys.argv[1],"mygeojson","ogr")

def runProcessingNativeBuffer(inputGeoJson, distance):
    processing.algorithmHelp("native:buffer")
    return processing.run("native:buffer",
                         {'INPUT': inputGeoJson,
                          'DISTANCE': distance, 'SEGMENTS': 5,
                          'END_CAP_STYLE': 0, 'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
                          'MITER_LIMIT': 2, 'DISSOLVE': False,
                          'OUTPUT': "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"})

ats = runProcessingNativeBuffer(vl, sys.argv[2])

vl1=ats['OUTPUT']

features = vl1.getFeatures()
exporter = QgsJsonExporter()
print("GEOJSON",exporter.exportFeatures(features))
```